# Tensorflow 2.2: custom gradient for a vector valued input/output custom layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using tensorflow 2.2 for my research and would like to implement a custom layer that takes in a vector(tensor) input and outputs a vector(tensor). My input/output relation is complicated and I need to create a function that computes the forward pass and the gradients. I came across the [custom_gradient function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient) that does the job. Unfortunately, what is totally unclear is how to use it for vector or tensor inputs and outputs. In particular, I have no idea how I need to return the Jacobian matrix or some form thereof.

As a simple example, let us say that my custom layer computes the vector-matrix product of the input a and the weights W (the weights). This is how I would approach the problem (skipping the steps to initialize weights, build etc. for simplicity).

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def custom_op(A,W):  # A is of size (#samples, length of input)
    result = tf.matmul(A,W) # I compute the output tensor.
    def custom_grad(dy):
        grad = ... # I have no idea what exactly grad stores, mathematically speaking
        return grad
    return result, custom_grad

class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__()

    def call(self, A):
        return custom_op(A, self.W)  # assuming self.W are the weights
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to define your own `custom_grad` function if you don't need customized gradient computation.

I would use `tf.GradientTape` outside of the layer call. The gradient tape watches the trainable variables and the operations performed on them. The `tape.gradient` function then alone computes the gradients. The following code snippet originates from this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff.

```
layer = CustomLayer()
x = tf.constant([[1., 2., 3.]])

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  # Forward pass
  y = layer(x)
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(y**2)

# Calculate gradients with respect to every trainable variable
grad = tape.gradient(loss, layer.trainable_variables)
```

You can apply the computed gradients by calling `apply_gradients` function on the instance of an optimizer to train your model.

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
training_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grad)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. On the other hand, I do need my own gradient function as the automatic gradient does not solve the problem I am interested in. So as I understand, applying the tape.gradient calculates the gradients corresponding to the forward pass, assuming all variables are continuous and unbounded, correct? On the other hand, this is not what I want and would like to customize my gradient.